# ¿Existe el ListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL) en RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy intentando usar un `RecyclerView` para simular un chat bien sencillo. Por mucho que he buscado y leído al respecto no encuentro la manera de hacer que mi RecyclerView mantenga visible el último item de la lista sin perder la animación de entrada del nuevo item. Estoy utilizando esto:
`list_data.add(data_item);
adapterRecyclerView.notifyItemInserted(list_data.size()-1);
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(list_data.size()-1);`
 Me funciona bien, pero cuando el recyclerView tiene que desplazarse más abajo para mostrar los nuevos items se pierde por completo la animación de entrada del item y eso precisamente es lo que no quiero que suceda. Por favor, agradecería mucho alguien que me ayude en esto. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución. En vez de utilizar
`recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(list_data.size()-1);`
Ahora utilizo:
`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(list_data.size()-1);`
De esta manera se mantienen las animaciones de entrada de los nuevos item. Al parecer no era posible mostrar la animación de desplazamiento y del Animator de los nuevos items al mismo tiempo. Gracias a todos